# How to use apply for different variables

Tags: r

I have three variables with names that I need to turn into a matrix of ones and zeroes, with columns for each name and in which a one means the name appeared anywhere in the five variables and zero means it did not. Something like this:

```
Var1   Var2   Var3  
Name1  Name2  Name3
Name1  Name4  Name5
Name3  Name5  Name6
Name2  Name3  Name4
```

And I need something like this

```
Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6
    1     1     1     0     0     0
    1     0     0     1     1     0
    0     0     1     0     1     1
    0     1     1     1     0     0
```

If it was a single name and a single variable I'd use `transform(data, Name1 = ifelse(Var1 == "Name1", 1, 0))`, but I don't know how to do it for all names and all variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
nm = sort(unique(unlist(df1)))
data.frame(setNames(lapply(nm, function(x)
    rowSums(sapply(df1, function(d) as.numeric(d %in% x)))), nm))
#  Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6
#1     1     1     1     0     0     0
#2     1     0     0     1     1     0
#3     0     0     1     0     1     1
#4     0     1     1     1     0     0
```

---

```
#DATA
df1 = structure(list(Var1 = c("Name1", "Name1", "Name3", "Name2"), 
                     Var2 = c("Name2", "Name4", "Name5", "Name3"),
                     Var3 = c("Name3", "Name5", "Name6", "Name4")),
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to achieve that-

```
data.table::setDT(df1)
df1 <- data.table::dcast(
    melt(df1[,rownm:=1:nrow(df1)], id.vars="rownm"), 
    rownm ~ value,
    length)


> df1[,-"rownm"]
   Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6
1:     1     1     1     0     0     0
2:     1     0     0     1     1     0
3:     0     0     1     0     1     1
4:     0     1     1     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 gather(var, val, -rowid) %>%
 add_count(rowid, val) %>%
 select(-var) %>%
 spread(val, n, fill = 0) %>%
 ungroup %>%
 select(-rowid)

  Name1 Name2 Name3 Name4 Name5 Name6
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1     1     0     0     0
2     1     0     0     1     1     0
3     0     0     1     0     1     1
4     0     1     1     1     0     0
```